# Eclipse plugin development Best practices

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

i am currently developing a eclipse plugin for our company. this plugin contains custom widget which has SWT Controlls. there are several listeners are attached with those controls and i want to know is it bad practice to implement the listeners inside custom widget GUI code. i have already created several external classes to handle some complex logic of the application. but still my custom widget GUI code contains long listener codes. is it bad practice or are there any good approach?

Comment: Anything using SWT controls will generally use several listeners.

Comment: thnk you for the comment.